# I implemented a timer in javascript, but what if javascript is disabled?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I have used a timer in my webpage implemented in JavaScript. but what if JavaScript is disabled? Will it remove the time constraint from the webpage? If that may be the case what should I do?

Comment: What exactly does this time constraint do?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are trying to do, but you can use a [meta refresh tag](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Meta_refresh) to redirect the user to another page (or the same page) after a given time interval.

This will potentially be horribly disruptive to the user experience.

Comment: please don't use this awful tag, it makes me cry.

Comment: I can think of only two reasons to use it: to keep a page periodically up-to-date without JS, and to demonstrate awful UX otherwise. Bonus points if there are blinking marquees and GIFs from the 90's.